# Proof sup C = sup A + sup B

Tags: analysis

So guys I need some help with these types of exercices. I am not sure if my proof is right and if so can I use it also for the others?

$Let \ A\subset \mathbb{R} \ and \ B\subset \mathbb{R} \ we \ define \ C= \left \{ a+b: a \epsilon A,b\epsilon B \right \}
\ We  \ want  \ to  \ prove:$

1) Inf C = Inf A + Inf B

2) sup C = sup A + sup B

3) Max C = Max A + Max B

4) Min C = Min A + Min B

Proof of 2) : Let us first show that A+B is bounded above given that A and B are bounded above.
Since A and B are bounded above, there exist α ∈ R and β ∈ R such that
a ≤ α for all a ∈ A, b ≤ β for all b ∈ B.
For any x ∈ A+B, there exist a ∈ A and b ∈ B such that x = a+b.

Thus, x = a+b ≤ α +β, which
shows that A+B is bounded above. Moreover, since supA is an upper bound of A and supB is an
upper bound of B, we have

x = a+b ≤ supA+supB.
This implies that supA+supB is an upper bound of A+B and, hence,

sup(A+B) ≤ supA+supB.

Fix any ε > 0, there exits a ∈ A and b ∈ B such that

supA−ε < a  and

supB−ε < b.

It follows that
supA+supB−2ε < a+b ≤ sup(A+B).
Since ε > 0 is arbitrary,

supA+supB ≤ sup(A+B).
Therefore, the given equality has been justified.

Comment: The proofs of all 4 statements are essentially the same. It seems that your existing proof only considers the case when the sups are upper-bounded.

Comment: To remove the burden of considering the cases when sups are bounded or not, I would just use existence of a sequence of points $a_n \in A$ and $b_n \in B$ such that $a_n\rightarrow \sup(A)$ and $b_n\rightarrow \sup(B)$. Then you get $a_n + b_n \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$ for all $n$, and the limit shows we can get there.

Comment: @Michael I just tried one proof and wanted to make sure it's true before i apply it to the others. And I'm not sure if i can use the limit as we haven't introduced it yet in class

Comment: In that case your proof seems fine, but needs to take care of the case when either $\sup(A)=\infty$ or $\sup(B)=\infty$.

Comment: @Michael thank's :)